# Navigation bar frame size calculation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I'm using the below lines for getting my navigation bar frame size it was working fine till iOS version 11 but after upgrading my iOS version to 11 its returning me nil value as (0, 0). Can anyone help me out with this issue.

```
CGRect frame = self.superview.frame;

            // Look for the navigation bar.
            UINavigationBar *navigationBar;
            UIView *superView = self;
            while (superView.superview)
            {
                if ([superView.superview isKindOfClass:[UINavigationBar class]])
                {
                    navigationBar = (UINavigationBar*)superView.superview;
                    break;
                }

                superView = superView.superview;
            }

            if (navigationBar)
            {
                CGSize navBarSize = navigationBar.frame.size;
                CGFloat superviewCenterX = frame.origin.x + (frame.size.width / 2);

                // Check whether the view is not moving away (see navigation between view controllers).
                if (superviewCenterX < navBarSize.width)
                {
                    // Center the display name
                    self.displayNameCenterXConstraint.constant = (navBarSize.width / 2) - superviewCenterX;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're never initializing the navigationBar, so I would assume you're attempting to get the navBarSize of null.

If you're using this code within a view controller that has a navigation bar, you might consider something along these lines:

```
UINavigationBar *navigationBar = self.navigationController.navigationBar;
CGSize navBarSize = navigationBar.frame.size;
```

If this doesn't suit your needs, I'd recommend adding additional example code/context of what's going wrong or what you're attempting to do.

Comment: Are you unable to get the frame using the Code you posted?  At what point in the view lifecycle are you using this code?  Are you sure the nav bar is on screen at this point?  I don't believe your code would work if the navBar is a subview of one of the superviews.